# Prevent hibernate entity changes from being persisted

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am updating my application from Spring Boot 1.4.5 / Hibernate 4.3.5 to Spring Boot 2.0.9 / Hibernate 5.2.18 and code that used to work in the previous configuration is no longer working.

The scenario is as follows:

1. Start a transaction by entering a method annotated with @Transactional
2. Hydrate the entity
3. Change the entity
4. Make another query
5. Detect a problem.  As a result of this problem, determine that changes should not persist.
6. Evict the entity
7. Exit the method / transaction

With Hibernate 4.3.5, calling entityManager.detach() would prevent the changes from being persisted.  However, with Hibernate 5.2.18, I'm finding that changes are persisted even with this call.  I have also tried to evict() from the session and I have tried to clear() all entities from the session (just to see what would happen).

So I ask - is it possible to discard entity changes in Hibernate 5.2.18 the way that I was able to do in Hibernate 4.3.5?

The relevant code is below...

```java
@Entity
public class Agreement {

    private Long agreementId;
    private Integer agreementStateId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "agreement_id")
    public Long getAgreementId() {
        return agreementId;
    }

    public void setAgreementId(Long agreementId) {
        this.agreementId = agreementId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "agreement_state_id", nullable = false)
    public Integer getAgreementStateId() {
        return agreementStateId;
    }

    public void setAgreementStateId(Integer agreementStateId) {
        this.agreementStateId = agreementStateId;
    }
}


@Component
public class Repo1 {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "rights")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void evict(Object entity) {
        entityManager.detach(entity);
    }

    public Agreement getAgreement(Long agreementId) {
        // Code to get entity is here.
        // Agreement with an agreementStateId of 5 is returned.
    }

    public void anotherQuery() {
        // Code to make another query is here.
    }
}


@Component
public class Service1 {

    @Autowired
    Repo1 repo;

    @Transactional
    public void doSomething() {
        Agreement agreement = repo.getAgreement(1L);

        // Change agreementStateId.  Very simple for purposes of example.
        agreement.setAgreementStateId(100);

        // Make another query
        repo.anotherQuery();

        // Detect a problem here. Simplified for purposes of example.
        if (agreement.getAgreementStateId() == 100) {
            repo.evict(agreement);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the `changeSomething` method doing? Are there any queries involved in there? Also you don't need to `unwrap` you can simply call `detach` on the `entityManager` to remove the entity (internally it calls `evict` but saves you a cast) and I would rename the field to `entityManager` instead of `entityManagerFactory` as it isn't the factory.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have made clarifying changes to the code, but the crux of the issue remains the same.  detach() provides the same results as evict().

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem and it has nothing to do with evict().  It turns out that an additional query was causing the session to flush prior to the evict() call.

In general, the application uses QueryDSL to make queries.  Queries made in this way did not result in the session flushing prior to making a query.  However in this case, the query was created via Session.createSQLQuery().  This uses the FlushMode already assigned to the session which was FlushMode.AUTO.

I was able to prevent the flush by calling setHibernateFlushMode(FlushMode.COMMIT) on the query prior to making the query.  This causes the session FlushMode to temporarily change until after the query has been run.  After that, the evict() call worked as expected.

Comment: Basically my second question in my initial comment. Beware that now the query might give a result you don't expect, as the results haven't been synchronized with the database yet. So unless you aren't querying the changed data there is no issue but it is something to take into account.